# When trying to run program in Eclipse, launching holds at 92%

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to launch a program in Eclipse but every time it gets stuck at 92% and says: *Starting virtual machine*. I can quit and start up Eclipse and it will run the first time, but then it keeps stops working. This just started happening so I'm not sure what's causing it.

[image]

Comment: Nope. Just booted up my computer today and its doing this. I did work on the project on a different computer yesterday and then imported it today.

Comment: Same problem here, started yesterday. No clue as what to do…

Comment: I reinstalled the JDK and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean it:

1. Right-click on the shortcut to Eclipse and say "properties
2. `"C:\Program Files(x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe" -clean` (change your path accordingly to your system)

Also could you give some further information? Like which Eclipse are you running on, are you trying to program a simple java application, or are you trying to develop an android app etc.

Comment: In my case, trying to debug a Java application. Has been working for ages, and yesterday suddenly stopped working (stuck at 92%)